# How can I access attributes of a context manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I want to accomplish something like:

```
class my_context(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj1 = Obj()
        self.obj2 = Obj()
        ...

    def __enter__(self):
        ''' initialize objects '''

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        ''' uninitialize objects '''
```

There are many `Obj` attributes which are resources which need to be be closed/deleted/etc. I was hoping to use a context manager to set them up and then get rid of them. However what I've found is that I cannot access the attributes when I try:

```
with my_context() as cont:
    cont.obj1  # doesn't work
```

Is there a way I can access these attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the `with... as` syntax to work, your `__enter__()` must return a value.

If you want to use the same attributes as your `my_context` class provides, you probably want to return `self`.